# How do I ask the user to input time

Tags: python, input, time

In Python how do I ask the user to input a time, then validate the answer into a correct time format?.

```
while True:
    try: 
        TimeInput = input("What time is it now ? :")
        ValidTime = ???????????????????????????????????
        print (ValidTime)
        break 
    except ValueError:
        print ("Use Format Hours: Minutes (HH:MM)")
```

Answer (score 1):

The [strptime](https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime) function may help you. It throws an exception if the input text is not a good datetime.
    import datetime

```
def get_input_time():
    while True:
        input = raw_input("What time is it now?\n")
        try: # strptime throws an exception if the input doesn't match the pattern
            input_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(input, "%H:%M")
            break
        except:
            print("Use Format Hours:Minutes (HH:MM)")
    return input_time

#test the function
input_time = get_input_time()
print("Time is %s:%s" % (input_time.hour, input_time.minute))
```

Comment: Brilliant Thank You! However, I had to replace raw_input with inout